Can't evaluate BLIP2 on a batch of images in parallel
I'm trying to speed up the generation of captions on a large set of images using BLIP-2. The below code for one image works fine:
prompt = "this is a picture of"
inputs = processor(trainData[0]["image"],text=prompt, return_tensors="pt").to(device, torch.float16)
generated_ids = model.generate(inputs.pixel_values,input_ids = inputs.input_ids, max_new_tokens=20)

But when I try to process it in batches (replacing e.g. trainData[0] with traindata[0:3]), it throws the error:
RuntimeError: shape mismatch: value tensor of shape [245760] cannot be broadcast to indexing result of shape [81920]

How can I get around this in order to sample captions in batches?
Here is what gemini suggested after some coaxing:
prompt = "this is a picture of"

inputs = processor(trainData[0:3]["image"], text=prompt, return_tensors="pt").to(device, torch.float16)

# Get the image embeddings from the model's encoder
image_embeds = shadow_model.get_base_model().vision_model(pixel_values=inputs.pixel_values).last_hidden_state

# Replace the <image> token embeddings with the image embeddings
image_token_index = processor.tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids("<image>")
inputs_embeds = shadow_model.get_base_model().embeddings(inputs.input_ids)
inputs_embeds[inputs.input_ids == image_token_index] = image_embeds

# Generate text using the modified inputs_embeds
generated_ids = model.generate(inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds, max_new_tokens=20)

# Decode and print the generated text
generated_text = processor.batch_decode(generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
print(generated_text)

is something like this really the best solution? I would have thought there is a more "native" way to do this...plus, the above code errors out. I tried to get gemini to fix it but to no avail.

Where do these processor and model.generate come from? Please include the relevant imports (and tags).
